# Replace Block in Layout for Specific Page

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, blocks, ce-1.8.1.0, magento-ce

At the controller `checkout_cart_index` with the reference `content`, I want to replace this:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
```

With this:

```
<block type="multicoupon/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
```

What happens is instead of *replacing the block*, it *adds a new one*. I've spent hours looking into this to no avail. Is there a way to do this with my own module using just the layout or will I have to write the change to a different file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because unsetChild isn't working in this case, I suggest the nuclear option:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"></remove>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

This will remove the block entirely. Not such a big deal because you'll immediately re-create it:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"></remove>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="multicoupon/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Also tried using the value from the original block's `as` attribute as the value for the `name` parameter for `unsetChild` (as per this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422641/magento-action-method-unsetchild-not-removing-a-block.

Comment: @DissidentRage see update. Tested as working in 1.8.

Comment: I seem to have left out a vital piece of information: I didn't notice before that `checkout.cart.coupon` happened to be a child of the block `checkout.cart`. After using `<action method="unsetChild"><name>checkout.cart.coupon</name></action>` again inside `<block name="checkout.cart"/>` it worked flawlessly. Thank you!